# JQuery validation with HTML

Tags: jquery, validation

I have built a form on a new website and was looking for some help with form validation using JQuery but not sure where to start. I have downloaded http://plugins.jquery.com/validationengine/. In the head tag referenced the JQuery Libary and the validatorEngine. Im not too sure now how to get the engine to work with my form. Below is my code:

```
<div id="form">

    <form method="post" action="mailto:" enctype="text/plain">
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="RECIPIENT" VALUE="">
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="SUBJECT" VALUE="enquiry">

      <div id="col1">
                <label>First Name</label><br />
                <input id="fname" name="first name" class="input" type="text" value=""/>
                <div id="clear"></div>

                <label>Surname</label><br />
                <input id="sname" name="Surname" class="input" type="text" value="" />
                <div id="clear"></div>

                <label>Telephone Number</label><br />
                <input id="tel" name="telephone" class="input" type="text" value="" />
                <div id="clear"></div>

                <label>E mail</label><br />
                <input id="email" name="email" class="input" type="text" value="" />
                <div id="clear"></div>

                <label>Message Subject</label><br />
                <select size="1" name="subject" id="subject">
                  <option>Please choose:</option>
                  <option>Beauty Treatments</option>
                  <option>Holistic & Massage Treatments</option>
                  <option>Pamper Parties / Events</option>
                  <option>After Care</option>
                  <option>Special Offers</option>
                  <option>Other</option>
                </select>
                <div id="clear"></div>
                </div>

                <div id="col2">                    
                <label>Message</label><br />
                <textarea id="message" name="notes" cols="" rows="" class="textarea"></textarea>

      </div>
```

Im new to JQuery and need to be told the bascis first please.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: Stack Overflow would be happy to help with any issues you encounter with the code you write, but I'm afraid the step-by-step tutorials isn't really what we do.  The plugin you reference has documentation to help you: http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/  Is there a specific piece of code in that documentation that you don't understand?  Or something you're trying which is behaving differently than expected?  If you need an overall tutorial on jQuery itself then I imagine there are many of those on the internet already.

Comment: You'll probably have better luck if you try some things first and post any issues you run into. If you are looking for a tutorial, try the docs for the validation engine plugin: http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/

Comment: your link has it all. validateEngine is all about decorating your markup with proper attributes. http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/. http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/index.html.

Comment: Ok maybe i did not make myself entirely clear. The part Just need some guidence with is getting my labels to reference the validation engine if something is not correct. So... if i took the email input and added

    class="validate[required,custom[email]] text-input"

What do the parts of this script call? Is that enough to get thescript to work?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this:

Download jquery validation engine plugin from [here.](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) And extract it.

Inside the folder you can find these two files.

```
jquery.validationEngine-en.js 
jquery.validationEngine.js
```

Copy & Paste in assets->scripts-> of your working project.

Then change the `src` path like below.

```
<script src="assets/scripts/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script src="assets/scripts/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

In Your Coding do the following:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#id of ur form").validationEngine();
    });
</script>


<label>First Name</label><br />
 <input id="fname" name="first name" class="validate[required,minSize[6],maxSize[10]]" type="text" value=""/>


 <label>Surname</label><br />
 <input id="sname" name="Surname" class="validate[required,minSize[6],maxSize[10]]" type="text" value="" />


 <label>Telephone Number</label><br />
 <input id="tel" name="telephone" class="validate[required,custom[onlyNumberSp],maxSize[10]]" type="text" value="" />


 <label>E mail</label><br />
 <input id="email" name="email" class="validate[required,custom[email],maxSize[30]]" type="text" value="" />
```